# Простой аккордеон на jQuery, по клику сразу закрывается при открытии

Tags: jquery

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".accTab").click(function() {
        $(".accContent").slideUp("fast");
      $(this).removeClass( "active" );
        if
         ($(this).next().is(":hidden") == true) {
            $(this).next().slideDown("normal");
          $(this).addClass( "active" );
        }
    });
    $(".accContent").hide()
});
```

```css
#accordion_wrapper {
 max-width: 800px;
 margin: 1em auto; 
 }
.accTab { 
 






 }
 .accTab:hover { 
  cursor:pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion_wrapper">
<div class="accTab">1</div>
 <div class="accContent">
    Content 1
    </div>
  <div class="accTab">2</div>
 <div class="accContent">
    Content 2
  </div>
<div class="accTab">3</div>
 <div class="accContent">
    Content 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Помимо кода, вопрос должен содержать описание проблемы. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    slides();

    $(window).resize(function() {// проверка размеров вьюпорта брузера "на лету"

        slides();
    
    })
    
});

function slides() {

    if($(window).width() > 550) {// тут заменить на необходимую ширину
        
        $(".accContent").hide();
        $(".accTab").click(function() {
            $(".accTab:not(this)").next().slideUp("fast");
            $(this).next(":not(:visible)").toggle("normal");
        });        

    }else{

        $(".accContent").show();
    }
}
```

```css
#accordion_wrapper {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto; 
}
.accTab:hover { 
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordion_wrapper">
<div class="accTab">1</div>
 <div class="accContent">
    Content 1
    </div>
  <div class="accTab">2</div>
 <div class="accContent">
    Content 2
  </div>
<div class="accTab">3</div>
 <div class="accContent">
    Content 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое ! а есть возможность добавить без перезагрузки страницы типо ajax?

Comment: @Виталий обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо ! работает только теперь при  открытие аккардеона скрипта он сразу закрывается

Comment: @Виталий обновил ответ. И немного переделал, удалил избыточность.

Comment: при нажатии еще раз он не закрывается (

Comment: @Виталий обновил ответ